# Multi-Optional type in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm curious why Swift doesn't automatically convert Multi-Optional type to Optional? 
Let's imagine we have this code:

```
var a: Int?? = 2
var b: Int? = a //error
```

All cases:

```
       Optional<Optional<2>>
                 /\
        .none       .some(Optional(Int))
                            /\
                       .none  .some(2)
```

So all cases are: `.none`, `.some(.none)`, `.some(2)`. Currently Swift automatically converts `Type` to `Optional<Type>` then why not do the same with `.some(.none)` to `.none`? I've partly solved this with extension method, but for example for `4-Optional`, method should be called 2 times, which is not good:

```
extension Optional {
    public func flatten<Result>() -> Result?
        where Wrapped == Result?
    {
        return self.flatMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! I think I finally understood what you mean. See the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think for the first code snippet you meant:

```
var a: Int? = 2
var b: Int?? = a
```

which compiles without error. Swift can implicitly convert `Int?` to `Int??`, the same way as converting `Int` to `Int?`

Your snippet:

```
var a: Int?? = 2
var b: Int? = a
```

does not compile because Swift cannot implicitly convert `Int??` to `Int?`, just as it cannot convert from `Int?` to `Int` implicitly.

Basically, Swift can implicitly *wrap* optionals, but cannot implicitly *un*wrap them.

> Currently Swift automatically converts `Type` to `Optional<Type>` then why not do the same with `.some(.none)` to `.none`

The two conversions you mentioned are not the same. Converting from `Type` to `Optional<Type>` always works and this is known at compile time. However, converting from `.some(.none)` to `.none` is not always possible because only at runtime do you know whether an optional is `.some` or `.none`, so Swift says "nope, I am not sure about this, so I am not allowing it".

In other words, to convert from `.some(.none)` to `.none`, you need to force unwrap:

```
let a: Int?? = .some(nil)

if case .some(.none) = a {
    print(".some(.none) confirmed")
}

let b: Int? = a! // force unwrap here

if case .none = b {
    print(".none confirmed")
}
```

otherwise Swift will say "What if the outer optional is `.none`?" and produce the compiler error you saw.

EDIT:

If you want to create a function that flattens an optional, you don't actually need to write such a function! The `as?` operator already does this job!

```
let a: Int??????? = 2
let b: Int? = a as? Int // as? unwraps every nested optional!
```

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation @Sweeper